# Error WFS (2.0.0) GetFeature spatial query with multi-surface geometries in ArcGIS Server 10.6

Tags: geometry, wfs, getfeature, surface

In the new version of ArcGIS Server 10.6 it is not possible to request GetFeature WFS with spatial filters with multi-surface geometry. The following is an example of the query:

[image]

GML3 geometry would be represented as:

```
> <gml:MultiSurface
> srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:6.9:6247"><gml:surfaceMember><gml:Polygon><gml:exterior><gml:LinearRing><gml:posList>98465.5842225004
> 106542.564601002 98498.638362525 106596.879798651 98570.0738671067 106561.465944204 98542.3330263732 106505.380223682 98465.5842225004 106542.564601002</gml:posList></gml:LinearRing></gml:exterior></gml:Polygon></gml:surfaceMember><gml:surfaceMember><gml:Polygon><gml:exterior><gml:LinearRing><gml:posList>98547.0558057572
> 106505.380685821 98581.8812200508 106557.334667689 98668.0733316556 106543.174764104 98634.4311531541 106465.24560996 98547.0558057572 106505.380685821</gml:posList></gml:LinearRing></gml:exterior></gml:Polygon></gml:surfaceMember></gml:MultiSurface
```

The POST query for the following case would be as follows:

WFS URL: http://www.secretariadeambiente.gov.co/arcgis/services/MapasVisorGeo/EEP_Reporte_Dec190/MapServer/WFSServer?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="2.0.0"
    xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0"
    xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0"
    xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2"
    xmlns:EEP_Reporte_Dec190='http://www.secretariadeambiente.gov.co/arcgis/services/MapasVisorGeo/Lote/MapServer/WFSServer'
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0
                        http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/2.0/wfs.xsd
                        http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2
                        http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd">
  <wfs:Query typeNames='EEP_Reporte_Dec190:EEP_Reporte_Dec190:Parques_Urbanos' srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:6.9:6247">
      <fes:Filter>
    <fes:Intersects>
    <fes:ValueReference>SHAPE</fes:ValueReference>
    <gml:MultiSurface><gml:surfaceMember><gml:Polygon><gml:exterior><gml:LinearRing><gml:posList>98465.5842225004 106542.564601002 98498.638362525 106596.879798651 98570.0738671067 106561.465944204 98542.3330263732 106505.380223682 98465.5842225004 106542.564601002</gml:posList></gml:LinearRing></gml:exterior></gml:Polygon></gml:surfaceMember><gml:surfaceMember><gml:Polygon><gml:exterior><gml:LinearRing><gml:posList>98547.0558057572 106505.380685821 98581.8812200508 106557.334667689 98668.0733316556 106543.174764104 98634.4311531541 106465.24560996 98547.0558057572 106505.380685821</gml:posList></gml:LinearRing></gml:exterior></gml:Polygon></gml:surfaceMember></gml:MultiSurface>
    </fes:Intersects>
     </fes:Filter>
    </wfs:Query>
</wfs:GetFeature>
```

And ArcGIS Server returns the following error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ExceptionReport
 version="2.0.0" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1 http://schemas.opengis.net/ows/1.1.0/owsAll.xsd">
    <Exception exceptionCode="InvalidParameterValue" locator="Unknown">
        <ExceptionText>
            <![CDATA[Unknown geometry type was found.]]>
        </ExceptionText>
    </Exception>
    <Exception exceptionCode="OperationProcessingFailed" locator="Unknown">
        <ExceptionText>
            <![CDATA[Operator 'Intersects' can't parse geometry.]]>
        </ExceptionText>
    </Exception>
</ExceptionReport>
```

It is to be noted that in version 10.4.1 this query worked correctly.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which stresses the importance of asking one question per Question.  Unfortunately, you don't seem to have *any* question in this Question.  Esri accepts bug reports both online and through Tech Support, where your contact information would be added to a list to be notified when a patch is ready.

Comment: same issue here, did you find a solution?